# Is there a way to bulk-download all texts from a certain Project Gutenberg bookshelf?

Tags: nlp, project-gutenberg

I need to download all .txt files from this [bookshelf](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/bookshelf/22).

Is it possible via wget? I can't seem to find any parametres to pass regarding the bookshelf categorizing.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little outdated but you can try https://github.com/aparrish/gutenberg-dammit

```
from gutenbergdammit.ziputils import searchandretrieve
for info, text in searchandretrieve("gutenberg-dammit-files-v002.zip", {'Title': 'Made Easy'}):
    print(info['Title'][0], len(text))
```